# $s_n(\lambda)$ is singular value of $P(\lambda)$. Why is $s_n(\lambda)$, countinuous in $\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let

- $A_j\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}, (j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$
- $P(\lambda) = A_m\lambda^m + \cdots + A_1\lambda  + A_0$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable. $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $P(\lambda )$ if $\det P(\lambda ) = 0$
- $s_n(\lambda)$ is singular value of $P(\lambda)$.

Why is $s_n(\lambda)$,  countinuous in $\lambda$?

Comment: Why would you write {\rm{P(}}\lambda {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{\lambda ^m} instead of P(\lambda) = A_m \lambda^n, yielding $P(\lambda) = A_m \lambda^n$? $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular values of $P(\lambda)$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $P(\lambda) P(\lambda)^*$.   The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  The roots of a monic polynomial (counted by multiplicity) are continuous functions of the coefficients, e.g. by the argument principle.